# What is the best way to compress balances stored in big.Int?

Tags: go, compression

I need to export Ethereum's (cryptocurrency) balances into Postgres, but I need to compress them in a blob, because they are too many and I have to store state for each block. Balances are stored in `big.Int`, but most accounts have 0 balance (or very close to zero), so I am thinking of this compression algorithm:

```
Format (single record): 
    8bits:  the length of the bit string
    following bits : the actual big.Int converted into bits with Int.Bits() function
```

The balances are stored with 1/10^18 precision, so 1 Ether is stored as 1 bit with 18 zeros. Would be my algorithm the best way to compress? Or is there any better idea for this?

For example, another idea would be to pick a float64 , but I am not sure if it can hold all the range of values. 1 Ether is a `1` with 18 zeros but cryptocurrency exchanges could have a balance of million Ethers, so the maximum would be `1` with around 25 zeros. Or I could pick float128 in the worst case.

What can you suggest?

Comment: Are you storing multiple data (balances) into a single record? why do you need to add a length?

Comment: Why are you compressing at all? And secondarily, why are you compressing at that level? Wouldn't it be better to handle compression at the database level (if supported by the db), or the block level (i.e. a compressed file system?)  Or more likely, only at the network layer (i.e. store it uncompressed, and only compress for transmission--which is probably where it matters)? Using a custom compression algo here makes your app more fragile and less future-proof. So the gains should be very high to even consider it. What gain are you aiming for?

Comment: @leafbebop, I have to add length because balances , when converted to bit strings will be variable. So, how do you know what is the length of your balance if you don't store it? If I pick a fixed length, then of course I don't need to store it,but I am afraid this is not going to be so effective at compression.

Comment: @Flimzy, I want to compress because there are 10 million accounts. If I take uncompressed data, say a balance taking 128 bit number (16 bytes), it would require 160,000,000 bytes, which is 152MB of data. That's a lot for a single postgers query , so a compression will help a lot, considering that many accounts have empty balance., I would say 50% have 0 balance, or even more.

Comment: @leafbebop, I want to store balances in a blob, in an ordered array, so the position of the balance in array matches the position of the account in the array of accounts. So, I am going to store 2 blobs, ordered account IDs and ordered balances.

Comment: I think the best algorithm in my case would be to sort the balances and store them in a dictionary-like structure. A balance would be the key, and the value would be the list of acount IDs having that balance. This way I would get maximum compression. Since account ID is only a uint, and balance can be up to 16 bytes, it makes sense.

Comment: I don't think I understand you but why are you implementing your own data structure on top of a database that is capable of doing so? Why don't create a row for each account?

Comment: @Nulik: "I think the best algorithm". Thinking is not enough. We need real data, real benchmarks.

Comment: @leafbebop , yeah, implementing my own data structure, otherwise the record overhead will kill my disk. The blockchain is now 500GB of data and it is growing every day. So, I have to think about efficiency beyond the database engine

Comment: 152MB is nothing for modern computers. Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maximum compression, use `Bytes()` (returns `[]byte`), not `Bits()` (returns `[]uint`). For example, a zero balance, a common value, is a one byte blob. Also, allow for negative balances. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func CompressBalance(i *big.Int) []byte {
    if i == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if i.BitLen() == 0 {
        return []byte{0}
    }
    byts := i.Bytes()
    if len(byts) > 0x7F {
        return nil
    }
    blob := make([]byte, 1+len(byts))
    blob[0] = byte(len(byts))
    blob[0] |= byte(i.Sign()) & 0x80
    copy(blob[1:], byts)
    return blob
}

func DecompressBalance(b []byte) *big.Int {
    if len(b) <= 0 {
        return nil
    }
    if 1+int(b[0]&0x7F) != len(b) {
        return nil
    }
    i := new(big.Int)
    if b[0] == 0 {
        return i
    }
    i.SetBytes(b[1:])
    if b[0]&0x80 == 0x80 {
        i.Neg(i)
    }
    return i
}

func main() {
    tests := []string{
        "0",
        "1925000288124900513257758",  // 1,925,000.288124900513257758
        "-1925000288124900513257758", // -1,925,000.288124900513257758
    }
    for _, s := range tests {
        i := new(big.Int)
        i, ok := i.SetString(s, 10)
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("error:", i, ok)
        }
        blob := CompressBalance(i)
        j := DecompressBalance(blob)
        fmt.Printf("i: %s\nj: %s\nblob: %d %v\n", i, j, len(blob), blob)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zClfVxG6agL

Output:

```
i: 0
j: 0
blob: 1 [0]
i: 1925000288124900513257758
j: 1925000288124900513257758
blob: 12 [11 1 151 162 121 135 80 245 19 41 153 30]
i: -1925000288124900513257758
j: -1925000288124900513257758
blob: 12 [139 1 151 162 121 135 80 245 19 41 153 30]
```

---

Financial transactions require exact numbers. By design, floating-point numbers are an approximation.